# How to Insert Multiples Rows in Database (SQL)

Tags: sql, databases, insert

I want to insert a matrix into a database, preferably with syntax like this:

```
SQLExecute[con, "INSERT INTO TABLE (x,y) VALUES (`1`, `2`)", {{1, 
   1,5,3,4}, {"A", "B", "C","B","D"}}]
```

so that I can write it like this:

```
SQLExecute[con, "INSERT INTO VARIABLE (x,y) VALUES (`1`, `2`)", 
    Matrix[[All,1]],Matrix[[All,2]]]
```

The problem is that *Mathematica* only allows the same number of values example:

```
SQLExecute[con, "INSERT INTO VARIABLE (x,y) VALUES (`1`, `2`)", {{1, 
   1}, {2, 2}}]
```

the number of values is two, so it requires the number columns as well as the number of rows to be two.

The boring way to do this is with `For` or `While`, reading each row and inserting it in database one by one. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass batch parameters to `SQLExecute`, we must specify the arguments as a single list-of-lists.  Each sublist is expected to contain one value for each parameter placeholder.  Thus, there is no need to split `Matrix` into its component columns using `Matrix[[All,1]],Matrix[[All,2]]`.  It is enough to say:

```
SQLExecute[con, "INSERT INTO VARIABLE (x,y) VALUES (`1`, `2`)", Matrix]
```

Here is a self-contained example, using an in-memory HSQL database:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

$matrix = {{1, "A"}, {1, "B"}, {5, "C"}, {3, "B"}, {4, "D"}};

$connection = 
  OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:."]];

SQLExecute[$connection, "CREATE TABLE myTable (x INTEGER, y VARCHAR(16))"];

SQLExecute[$connection, "INSERT INTO myTable (x, y) VALUES (`1`, `2`)", $matrix];

SQLExecute[$connection, "SELECT * FROM myTable"]
(* {{1, "A"}, {1, "B"}, {5, "C"}, {3, "B"}, {4, "D"}} *)

SQLExecute[$connection, "SHUTDOWN"];

CloseSQLConnection[$connection];
```

Note how the arguments to the `INSERT` statement were passed in the same format as the rows retrieved by the `SELECT` statement.